# Run on specific self hosted servers using Azure pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

In Azure git, I am running some self-hosted agents which live in the pool called "Default".

In an Azure pipeline (.yml file) I can tell the job that it has to run in a specific agent like this

```
pool:
  name: Default
  demands:
  - Agent.Name -equals MACHINE1
```

But what if I have, for example, 4 machines and I want it to run on machine 1 or 2 but not on machine 3 or 4?

I would have thought it would look something like this:

```
pool:
  name: Default
  demands:
  - Agent.Name -equals MACHINE1 -or MACHINE2
```

or maybe a wildcard:

```
pool:
  name: Default
  demands:
  - Agent.Name -equals MACHINE*
```

but neither of those work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. You can do this by giving the servers different User-defined capabilities.

If you go to Project Settings > Agent pools > Default > Agents > (click on Agent) > Capabilities then you can add a Capability that for example is the same for MACHINE1 and MACHINE2 but different for MACHINE3 and MACHINE4.

Then you can test the capability in the pipeline and it will select only in the servers with that value set:

```
pool:
  name: Default
  demands:
    - MyVar -equals Group1
```

Comment: Another neat trick here (and this is useful where your agent set is dynamic) is that all environment variables on the agent machine are exposed as capabilities, so if you're on Windows, you can demand `- COMPUTERNAME -equals MACHINE*`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#capabilities

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, you could Accept it as an Answer, it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Is it possible for the pipeline to determine which agent is available in the pool? Say I have an agent pool with two agents installed. If one my pipelines is using agent1 to run the build and another pipeline has been triggered, is there a way to configure it in such a way that if it sees that agent1 is being used then it will use agent2 instead, and vice-versa?

Comment: @Sohlae I think I'm missing something in your question, because that's how agent pools already behave by default. If one agent is being used, the other one is used, and one agent doesn't get used for 2 pipelines at once.