# How to select any of two agents from a pool of 3 Self hosted agents

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a self hosted pool of 3 Mac machines. For a specific stage, I need the flexibility to run it on either of two specific agents in this pool. Is it possible to specify this?

e.g.

```
demands:

    - or(agent.name -equals Agent1, agent.name -equals Agent2)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Chubsdad; the mechanism to do this is agent Capabilities and Demands. I'm sure there'll be a previous answer describing how this works, so I'll dig it out for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run on specific self hosted servers using Azure pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66286505/run-on-specific-self-hosted-servers-using-azure-pipelines)

Comment: @VinceBowdren: Thanks for sharing the link. I did go through that before the post. I am looking at being able to use basic AzDo expressions to select a set of agents from the pool.